# Does interrupting ajax function stop it from being completed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ffmpeg

What i'am trying to do is converting a video by using ffmpeg which take a long time to complete by sending ajax request to the server but without making the user wait until the video conversion done.

if the user refresh the page after the request is sent dose that stop the function form completing ?
is this  a good way or i should make a queue for video converting ?

Comment: `if the user refresh the page after the request is sent dose that stop the function form completing` That issues a user abort and if your server does not ignore user aborts then yes that (php) function will stop

Comment: Thank you, I think that my server ignore user aborts i have to check that. if it's ignore then there is no problem right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following structure;

- When user started video conversion, send request to backend via ajax to convert
- When request sent, you can set a cookie on server side (it can be readable on browser also).
- After request sent, you can show a processing bar.
- When user refresh page, you will check cookie value if any video conversion started or not. If exists, you can continue showing progress bar again.
- When conversion finished, you can set cookie value to done, and ajax check call tell the status of conversion to user.

I assume you are making ajax call in specific time interval to get status of conversion. If not using [ajax poll](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp), you can use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to send result back to browser client. Cookie values can be modifiable by client, so it will be good if you encrypt cookie value, or make video conversion page to restricted page. If video conversion page restricted to registered users only, you can set conversion status in db instead of cookie.